# How to draw shapes in maps using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I need to create an App where the users (growers and agronomists) navigate in a Map like google maps and they need to be able to delimitate where their fields are and the app needs to calculate the area of them.

I still don't know if it is better in terms of usability to draw shapes or to place pins that would get connected forming a polygons.

It is a big challenge and I would highly appreciate insights about this as well as any 3rd party libraries suggestion.

I have built a prototype using TK.CustomMap (https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) where the users can drop pins to mark their fields but they say pins are not enough for them. They want to draw shapes.

Thanks

Comment: You could probably use SkiaSharp to draw over top of the map. Not something I have ever done and I would imagine you would need to watch out for performance on slow devices.

Comment: You should use dependency injection to do the map drawing at the native level.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection/